# How to set in my application Sleep after 5 minutes of screen inactivity in Android?

Tags: android, android-settings

Which `uses - permission` do I need to use for this?

And how do I show the settings for the user to activate it?

Comment: what do you mean by "passive" screen - is it when nothing has been detected from a user?

Comment: yes, in the settings it's call: "sleep after 5 minutes of inactivity"

Comment: ok i understand, do you want your app to open the display settings and make the user pick which one they want?

Comment: if i can do it without, thats greate but i thinck it is kind of system permission witch you must ask the user, so if i can do it before the aplication instaled , will be better than to ask on run time

Comment: it's possible for your app to use an intent to open the system display settings page and let the user pick for themselves which sleep setting they want.

Comment: do you have work code for that?

Comment: yes, i just added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app to show users their display settings, you can achieve this with an intent:

```
Intent displaySettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(displaySettingsIntent);
```

You can add the code to a button click, so when users click on that button, their phone's display settings will be shown to them, and they can pick whichever one they want (15 secs, 30 secs, 1 minute, etc).

**Note**: This code will switch from your app to the display settings page and to return to your app, users will need to press the back button.

Comment: thats worked but it is not only to my app, this changes the system settings of all apps

Comment: yes. that's the operating system's display settings, all apps will be affected by the change.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep is a device OS Feature and only accessible to System Apps. You can lock sleeping by using WACK_LOCK permission.

To enable it:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

To disable it:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: meybe I didn't understand , but it didn't do any change to me, what is a system app? it can be done only on root device?

Comment: System app are bind with Android OS. That is preinstalled and you can not uninstall that. The given code is for keeping app active. For eg. if you want to build a media player then you need to WAKE_LOCK that is FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON so that device prevented to sleep until media is playing.